# Ajax Toolkit Calendar Issue

Tags: asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have ajax calendar on many pages, I am facing a little issue
that wont get fixed inspite of my efforts, I tried a lot of things, to get
it to its current state, just one thing left when year or month changed, it will
hide the weekdays on top, and strangely it will show later months as per the
following image

[image]

following is code I have:

```
.test .ajax__calendar_body
{
background-color: #e9e9e9;
border: solid 1px #cccccc;
width:200px;
}
.test .ajax__calendar_invalid
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}



         .fstCol
    {
      text-align: right;
      float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
      display:table-column;         

      height:auto;
      margin-right: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      /*padding: 4px 0px;*/
    }

    .scndCol
    {
      text-align: left;
      float:left;/*fix for  buggy browsers*/
      display:table-column;         
      width:394px;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
      /*padding: 4px 0px;*/
    }




                <div class="fstCol">Date Of Birth</div>
                <div class="scndCol">

                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" CssClass="whiteCtrl"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:CalendarExtender CssClass="test"  ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDOB">
                    </asp:CalendarExtender>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtDOB" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>
```

Comment: I dont know how it works, but setting Animated="False" worked for calendar extender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes
It was the real issue
setting the property `Animated="false"`
did the trick

otherwise the calendar either hid the last column (Saturday)
or behaved like the one I posted screenshot for